# Log4j Log is not created when jar file run

Tags: java, log4j

This is my *Student* class that used to test log4j.

```
public class Student{    
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Student.class.getName());   

    public Student() {  
         PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");  
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){  
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "My log4j Test");    
    } 
}
```

This is my *log4j.properties* file

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,Appender1,Appender2
log4j.appender.Appender1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Appender2=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Appender2.File=C:/Log4j/MyLogExample.log

log4j.appender.Appender1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout`  
log4j.appender.Appender1.Target=System.out`   
log4j.appender.Appender1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n`  

log4j.appender.Appender2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout`  
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n`  

log4j.appender.Appender2.MaxFileSize=50KB`  
log4j.appender.Appender2.MaxBackupIndex=10`
```

When I run this program using Eclipse *MyLogExample.log* file gets created. But after I have created a jar file and run it using the command prompt, the log file is not created.

in console i can see this error.

```
log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file [log4j.properties]. 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: log4j.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

After I add the following code example, the log file is created even when the jar file run with command prompt.

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("C:\\eclipeworkspace\\Log4jTest\\log4j.properties");
```

How I can give relative path instead of exact path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`log4j.properties` should be in your classpath. Add it to the classpath when running from command line.

A better alternative is to specify the property file using

`-Dlog4j.configuration=relative path/log4j.properties`

from the command line. 
In this case you can remove the line `PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");` from your code - you don't need to do anything in the code to specify the property file.

Answer (score 4):

Use this :

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL url = classLoader.getResource("log4j.properties");
File file = new File(url.toURI());
```

Comment: Or a bit shorter: `PropertyConfigurator.configure(classLoader.getResource("log4j.properties"));`. @Pradeep  This assumes that the `Log4jTest` directory is on the classpath, so you'll have to check your eclipse project config.

Comment: I have added this code section 

ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(classLoader.getResource("log4j.properties"));
but still same error?

Comment: log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file from URL [null].

Comment: I have put log4j.properties file in class path. then Load using following code. Now Log4j Logger is working. ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(classLoader.getResource("log4j.properties"));

Answer (score 0):

add this plugin if using maven to make your jar runnable wilth all depenencies

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>cnnc.bcyr.nvnvn.nch.MainclassName</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```